# Why fputs() only add one word in a file?

Tags: c, file-handling

In this program my edit() function is not working properly.When i try to write something it just erase the whole content and in the appendText() only one word gets appended?Is there any way to write the whole string to the file?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



main(void){

    char fName[100];

    printf("Enter file name :\n");
    scanf("%s",&fName); //File Name

    int choice;
    printf("Enter your choice : \n1.Edit text\n2.Read the contents of the file\n3.Append text\n4.Exit\n");  //Enter choice
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice){

        case 1 :
            edit(fName);        //Edit text
            break;
        case 2 :
            readContents(fName); //Read file    
            break;
        case 3 :
            appendText(fName);      //Append 
            break;  
        case 4 :
            exit(0);            //Exit
            break;
        default :
            printf("Invalide Option!\n"); 
            break;      
    }//End switch

}//End main

//Function to edit contents of the file
void edit(char file[100] ){

    int line,temp = 0;
    printf("Enter the line no. to be edited : \n");
    scanf("%d",&line);  //Line no

    char sentence[100];
    printf("Enter the content : \n"); 
    scanf("%s",sentence);

    char str[100];
    FILE *fName = fopen(file,"w");

    while(!feof(fName)){

        temp++;
        fgets(str,99,fName);

        if(line == temp)
            fputs(sentence,fName); break;

    } 

    printf("\nContents of the file has been updated!\n");

    fclose(fName);


}//End edit()

//Function to read the contents of the file

void readContents(char file[100]){

    char str[100];
    FILE *fName = fopen(file,"r");
    while(!feof(fName)){
        puts(fgets(str,99,fName));
    } 

    fclose(fName);
    printf("\n");
} //End readContents()


//Funtion to append string to an existing file

void appendText(char file[100]){

    char str[100];
    FILE *fName = fopen(file,"a");

    printf("Enter your string :\n");
    scanf("%s",&str);

    fputs(str,fName);   

    fclose(fName);
    printf("\nText added to the file\n");


}//End of append()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really just change the contents of a (text) file to change one line in the way you're doing. When you write the new string in, you're overwriting the rest of the file. You need to read the whole file in to memory, change the line you want, and then write the entire thing out to file. Or, read from the file, write each line out to a second file (replacing the text when you find it), and then delete/rename the files.

As for the appendText, from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ on %s (emphasis mine):

> Any number of **non-whitespace** characters, stopping at the first **whitespace** character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

I.e., your scanf for the append is only reading the first word, thus why only the first word is being appended.

Comment: How do i read the file in the memory and then change it's content?

Comment: You'd probably need to use arrays, and dynamic memory allocation (`malloc/free`). It might just be easier to use the 2-file method until you learn more about the language; that way, you only need to handle one line worth of text at a time.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many problems with this code is that when you open the file with mode `"w"` you *erase all of its existing contents*.  If you don't want to do that, use mode `"r+"` instead.